# The player ranking goes wrong with me?

Tags: javascript

I want if the player answer correctly:
0 questions from 5 he will get (No Crown)
1 -2 questions from 5 he will get (Bronze Crown)
3 -4 questions from 5 he will get (Silver Crown)
5 questions from 5 he will get (Golden Crown)

but I get different results and I don't know why

```
var question1 = prompt("What is the capital of Egypt?");
var question2 = prompt("What is the capital of USA?");
var question3 = prompt("What is the capital of France?");
var question4 = prompt("What is the capital of UK?");
var question5 = prompt("What is the capital of Germany?");

var questiontrack = 0;
var playerRanking = 0;

if (question1.toUpperCase() == 'CAIRO') {
    questiontrack += 1;
} 

if (question2.toUpperCase() === 'WASHINGTON') {
    questiontrack += 1;
}

if (question3.toUpperCase() === 'PARIS') {
    questiontrack += 1;
}

if (question4.toUpperCase() === 'LONDON') {
    questiontrack += 1;
}

if (question5.toUpperCase() === 'BERLIN') {
    questiontrack += 1;
}

document.write('<h1>'+'You answerd '+ questiontrack+ ' questions right from 5 questions' +'</h1>')



if (questiontrack === 5) {
    playerRanking = ' Golden Crown'
} else if (questiontrack === 3 && questiontrack <= 4) {
    playerRanking = 'Silver Crown'
} else if (questiontrack === 1 && questiontrack <= 2) {
    playerRanking = 'Bronze Crown'
} else {
    playerRanking = 'No Crown'
}

document.write('<h1>'+'You got the '+playerRanking+'</h1>')
```

Comment: Think about the logic e.g. here: `questiontrack === 3 && questiontrack <= 4`.

Comment: Should be `if (questiontrack === 5) {
    playerRanking = ' Golden Crown'
} else if (questiontrack >= 3 && questiontrack <= 4) {
    playerRanking = 'Silver Crown'
} else if (questiontrack >= 1 && questiontrack <= 2) {
    playerRanking = 'Bronze Crown'
} else {
    playerRanking = 'No Crown'
}`

Comment: You have already checked for `5` above. So, just `else if(questiontrack >= 3)` and `else if (questiontrack >= 1)` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

problem in the logic

```
questiontrack === 3 && questiontrack <= 4
```

it should be

```
questiontrack >= 3 && questiontrack <= 4
```

Comment: The `&&` is not even needed

Comment: @charlietfl `&&` is required

Comment: Not really ... these are `else if` conditionals

Answer (score 0):

could be refactored to

```
if (questiontrack === 5) {
    playerRanking = ' Golden Crown'
} else if (questiontrack >= 3) {
    playerRanking = 'Silver Crown'
} else if (questiontrack >= 1) {
    playerRanking = 'Bronze Crown'
} else {
    playerRanking = 'No Crown'
}
```